# Hill climbing extremist

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

Imagine you are on a trip in mountains, but you are a bit nutter and you walk only straight uphill or downhill. If you are on the top of a mountain or in a valley you can walk in any direction.

The question is: Can you get from any point to any another point?

---

In more mathematical language. Imagine you have a smooth function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In order to dismiss simple counter examples we require that $\phi$ coercive or is zero at infinity. Now be given two points $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^2$, can you find piece-wise smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma'$ has the same or opposite direction as $\nabla \phi(\gamma(t))$, except at the points where $\nabla \phi = 0$? This can be stated, after reparametrization of $\gamma$, as $|\gamma' \cdot \nabla \phi| = \|\gamma'\|\|\nabla \phi\|$.

---

Background: I was thinking about this differential equation for $u$
$$
f = g_i \partial_i u.
$$
you can find local solution of by integrating the function $f$ along integral curves of $g_i$. But when can you glue these solutions together and get a globally continuous solution? This should be possible when you can get from point $A$ to point $B$ by different paths but you integrate the same amount of $f$. So natural question is, can you get from any point $A$ to any point $B$?

I found this question interesting but surprisingly I was unable to find a (simple) argument why it should be true.

Comment: I'd like to understand your background question. Are $f$ and $g_i$ assumed to be known? Are $g_i$ derivatives or just components of some $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$? What do you know about these functions?

Comment: The question is: given $f$ and $g_i$, find $u$ such that $f = g_i \partial_i u$. Assume what ever smoothness and other qualities of $f$ and $g_i$ such that you are able to give me an interesting answer.

This question originated out of my desire to understand PDEs and out of my embarrasment that even for PDEs of the most simplest form I know close to nothing.

Comment: If you're interested in the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) (as this is what you're using), you can look up Evans' PDE book for general conditions for solvability; as we see on your example, there is some geometric structure hidden there. Also, if $g$ is an arbitrary function and not necessarily a gradient, things get harder. And also some assumptions on $f$ are needed. 
But anyway, your main question is valid, it's just that its application to the background question is not straightforward.

Comment: I looked through Evans some time ago and I could not find the answer. Doesn't he only talk only about local existence? I'm looking for global existence.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thought this through, but at the same time it would take too much space as comment, so let me describe an idea I have for this problem.

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$
**Idea.** The relation $x \sim y$ if there is a path joining $x$ and $y$ is an equivalence relation in $\R^2$. If you can only prove that each equivalence class is open, then your claim follows from connectedness of $\R^2$.

Other observations:

- I would expect that one needs some assumptions on behavior of $\vp$ in infinity, so it could be easier to work on a torus or a sphere first, and then see what is needed in the case of $\R^2$.
- It is surely important that our vector field is a gradient field. On a torus any nonzero constant vector field yields a counterexample, so one probably needs to use the growth of $\vp$ in some way.
- To make things clearer, I would add an additional assumption that $\vp$ is a Morse function. This way we can be sure what happens at points where $\nabla \vp = 0$.

Comment: I like the idea of using connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I would expect that the proof would go roughly like this:
For contradiction, we assume that we have point $x$ and points $y_n$ such that $y_n \rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. and that $y_n$ are not in the same component at $x$. Any path going uphill has to reach a critical point. Denote $c(a)$ the critical point reached by going uphill from point $a$. The naive hope is that $c(y_n) \rightarrow c(x)$, however this is not true since I can think of a counter example.

Comment: After some thought, if $c(y_n) \rightarrow c(x)$ then you should be done(you have to show that there is a direction from $c(x)$ such that you hit one of the paths originating from $y_n$ for high enought $n$). 

In case that $c(y_n)$ does not converges to $c(x)$, you should be able to pick new $x^1 = c(x)$ and $y^1_n$ such that $y^1_n \rightarrow c(x)$ such that $y^1_n$ and $c(x)$ are not in the same component. This set us up into the original setting and we can do the whole argument again.

Comment: This way we construct a sequence $x^m$ and $y^m_n$. If the sequence is finite in $m$ then we are done. Not sure what to do, when the sequence is infinite.

Comment: As for finiteness - if we work with a Morse function on a closed surface (or $\mathbb{R}^2$ with infinity somehow out of the picture), then there are only finitely many critical points, and this should help. Other than this, right now I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Right, working with Morse function on a surface simplifies stuff. I think that the case two(missing $c(x)$) can only happen around saddle points. After some hopping over critical points, you have to reach maximum point where(I expect) the first case has to happen. However there is a problem with my argument. I assumed that $x$ is not a critical point but $x^1$ is critical. It is not clear what uphill means at $x^1$, but you can probably take a limit of uphill directions at points $y^1_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general the answer is no. It will depend on the regularity of $\phi$ and on the points $A$ and $B$. Your problem is a particular case of the following problem:

> Given a continuous vector field $X: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and points $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^2$, is there a curve $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\gamma(0)=A$, $\gamma(1)=B$ and $\gamma'(t) = X(\gamma(t))$, for every $t\in(0,1)$?

In your case, $X$ is the gradient field $X = \nabla \phi$.

If we drop the condition $\gamma(1)=B$, then we have  [Cauchy-Peano Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem). But we can't ensure that $\gamma(1) = B$ in general. For example, let's consider the constant vector field $X = (1,0)$ (notice that $X$ is also a gradient field) and let $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(0,1)$ be the points. It's easy to verify that there is no curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = A$, $\gamma(1)=B$ and $\gamma'(t) = (1,0)$, for every $t\in(0,1)$. Now this example doesn't vanish in the infinity, but you can get the idea to convince yourself. The point is that once you have the field $X$, the integral lines will be determined. So if you don't have at least $A$ and $B$ on the same integral line, you will not have a solution passing through them.

Comment: Sorry I had to down vote. Your answer is not helpfull in any way. Your 'counter example' is the exact reason why $\phi$ has to be zero at infinity. The variational formulation does not make any sense. Constant paths minimizies the integral or paths that are perpendicular to the $\nabla \phi$. I'm not interested in such paths.

Comment: And important thing is that I'm not looking for integral curves of some vector field, because you cannot get into point, where the field is zero, in finite time(vector field has to be lipschitz). But in my question such a points play very important role.

Comment: The second part in my comment is, in fact, wrong because I misunderstood your problem. But the first part still make sense. Though I have given an example that doesn't vanish at infinity, as I said, you can easily figure out the idea. If you want paths with velocity parallel to the field $\nabla\phi$, then you want basically integral curves of such field. And in general there is no such integral curves passing through any two points given. 

P.S.: Before to down an answer, try to communicate of the person who wrote it. Nobody comes here to spend their time writing wrong responses.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out your idea. Please give me a counterexample which satisfies my conditions, than I will be happy, but now I do not find your answer helpful. I believe that you still misunderstand my question, have in mind following simple example:

Comment: Imagine single hill. In order to get from point A to point B, you go straight uphill and you get on the top of this hill then you go downhill in the direction you would come from if you started in the point B, in this way you get to point B. Such a path is not an integral curve of that vector field.

Comment: Walner, Any progress? Do you have an example for me which shows that it is not possible?